# How to send JSON from a local website to AWS IoT?

Tags: javascript, html, json, aws-iot

I am modifying a website that, when the user clicks a button, downloads a json file. I was wondering if there were a way that I could automatically get this in a way that I could then access it in AWS IoT Core.

Basically, a micro-controller reads information from a machine and then hosts the website on its own IP. The downside to this is that it only works if the user is on the same network as the controller.

I have already created everything needed to receive the json in the AWS IoT Core (from a previous project where the json was already being sent to AWS), I just need a way to get the information there. Any help would be more than appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
I think this should be the necessary code, however, I am not 100% sure.

```
//Save the selected parameter values  into the file
        $(".SaveImg").click(function () {
            //Step 1 : create the JSON for selected parameter values to be saved in file
            //var SelectedSubParam = sel;
            var str = "{\"ID\":" + sel + ",";
            str += "\"param\": [";

            //To define whether the selected parameters have value or not
            var hasValue = false;

            //To check whether parameters has selected or not
            var isSelected = false;

            $.fn.getSelectedParameterRows().each(function (idx, item) {
                if ($(item).css("display") != "none") {
                    isSelected = true;
                    var paramValue = $(this).children().eq(1).children("input[type='text']").val().trim();

                    //Save the parameters which has value otherwise don't save it
                    if (paramValue != "" && ($(this).children().eq(1).children("input[type='text']").css("visibility") != 'hidden')) {
                        hasValue = true;
                        str += "{\"Name\":\"" + $(this).children().eq(0).text().trim() + "\",";

                        str += "\"Address\":\"" + $(this).children().eq(1).children("input[type='text']").attr('Id') + "\",";
                        str += "\"Value\":" + paramValue;
                        str += "},";
                    }
                }

            });
            //Remove ',' from last param set to make a valid JSON 
            str = str.slice(0, -1);
            str += "]}";

            //Step 2: Create and save the Text file
            if (hasValue) {
                // To save text file in windows default location 
                // Commented since this code is not working for Mobiles
                /*var txt = makeTextFile(str);
                console.log($(".SaveImg").attr("href",txt));
                $(".SaveImg").attr("download", "ParameterExport.txt");*/

                // Create and save the file in downloads folder in client place using File saver API
                var blob = new Blob([str], { type: "text/plain;base64" });
                saveAs(blob, "ParameterExport.txt");
            }

            else if (!isSelected) {

                if ($.fn.getParameterCount() > 0) {
                    alert("Please select Parameters !!");
                }
                else {
                    alert("No parameters available!!");
                }
            }
            else {
                //Show alert if all the selected parameters don't have the value
                alert("File cannot be saved since selected variables don't have values !!");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you have any code to share? I am assuming that, if you click a button to download the `json`, you have that `json` data in your Javascript, which you could use to make a `POST` to AWS.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro Being as the app to program the microcontroller also creates the website, the javascript is an atrocious, un-formatted mess. Is there something specific I could use the find function for? Like a keyword or phrase? Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro I think I added the correct code. If not, let me know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like the variable `str` is your final JSON. Since your code is already using jQuery, you can use it's AJAX function to `POST` that JSON to your AWS. Check this link if you need a reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

you could take benefits of AWS lambda where you can either keep that json stored in S3 bucket or fetch it at runtime from website.

After fetching that json from S3 / fetch from site, you can publish an message to IoT core topic to which you're microcontroller is subscribed and your microcontroller will then receive it.

Comment: I am actually looking to send the json the other direction, from the microcontroller to AWS IoT core. I have edited my question to include what I think should be the needed javascript code. Thanks for the help!